# I have a question about OOP .I Need Your help !

Tags: oop

Please see the code below :

```
package bk;

public class A { 
    protected void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Calling the method A !");
    }
}

// And I have an another package :   

package com;
import bk.A;

public class B extends A {
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("Goi phuong thuc B !");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         A a = new B();
         a.methodA();

    }
}
```

How can I allow `a` to call `methodA()`?

Comment: doesn't protected mean it's visible just within the package (bk) ? it should be fine if you make methodA public since B lives in package com and A lives in package bk

Answer (score 6):

Cause methodA() is protected and it can be called within derived classes only. Change it to public if you want to call it like this

Comment: @Daniel: in a static method...?

Comment: Accroding the Sun's tutorials :The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.If so,I am wrong or they are wrong ? here.The Class B extends A,but B in an another package.

Comment: @OOP you can call methodA() in methodB() without creating an instance.

Comment: @OOP: You answered your own question with that statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Protected methods can only be called from within the class itself, or from derived classes.

The `a` variable is declared as a variable of type `A`. Class `A` itself has no publicly available `methodA`, so you cannot call it.

Yes, you assign a new `B` instance to the `a` variable and the `a.methodA()` statement is inside the derived `B` class, but the compiler only sees that `a` is of type `A`. It could be **any other subclass** of `A` as well, in which case you still wouldn't have access to `methodA`.

You'll have to tell the compiler that the `a` variable is actually of type `B`. Then you will be able to call `methodA`, because you're calling it from within class `B`.

```
B a = new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `methodA()` like it is public. Declaring simply `methodA()` in the B class is fine, but you cannot do `a.methodA()`.

Conversely if it wasn't a method and simply `protected int a;`
you could do

`a = 1;` in class `B`

but

```
A a = new A();
a.a = 1;
```

is not legal

A `protected` method is visible to inheriting classes, even not part of the same package. A package scope (default) method is not. That is the only difference between protected and package scope.

The theory is that someone extending your class with `protected` access knows more about what they are doing than someone who is merely using it with `public` access. They also need more access to your class’s inner workings. Other than that, `protected` behaves like default package access.